# Слова казнь и казеный однокоренные слова?

Tags: этимология

Слова казнь и казеный однокоренные слова?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, эти слова имеют разное происхождение.

*Казнь* исторически произошло от глагола *каяться* или от глагола *казать*. Оно исконно славянское.

Казённый — производное от слова *казна*. Последнее было заимствовано из тюркских языков в древнерусскую эпоху.

Таким образом, слово *казнь* — исконное, а казённый в конечном счёте восходит к тюркскому корню.